# Switch statement outputs the case followed by the default

Tags: c

I have the code below as part of a C program to change direction. Whenever I run the code, the output is always the case followed by the default. Why is this happening and how can I stop the default showing every time?

Thanks

Output Example:

Enter command: W

Sorry, You can't go that way. Please enter another direction:
Sorry, that's not a direction. Please enter either N, E, S or W:

```
printf("\nEnter command:"); while (1) {
    scanf_s("%c", &ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 'w':
    case 'W':
        printf("\nSorry, You can't go that way. Please enter another direction:");
        break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        printf("\nSorry, You can't go that way. Please enter another direction:");
        break;
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
        printf("\nSorry, You can't go that way. Please enter another direction:");
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
        printf("Goodbye!\n");
        exit(0);
    default:
        printf("\nSorry, that's not a direction. Please enter either N, E, S or W:");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: linefeed in the buffer try: `scanf_s(" %c", &ch);`

Comment: The `”%c”` format collects the newline on the second call, and ends up in the default.  Use `” %c”` with a leading space.

Comment: Also, I think the the `scanf_s` function wants you to specify the length of the buffer, which is 1 for `%c`: `scanf_s(" %c", &ch, 1);`

Comment: or just use `scanf` and drop the "safe" functions that everyone misuses, which defeat the "safe" purpose

Comment: Thanks Guys. Adding the space before the %c worked. Appreciate the help